# Unable to store value of a variable using AJAX in PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax

This is my html Form. From here I am passing 3 values to my ajax

```
<div class="form-container">
     <h3>Drop me a line</h3>
     <p id="response"></p>
     <form role="form" id="form">
<div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" cols="50" id="message1" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
 </div>
 <button type="submit" id="email-button" class="btn btn-danger btn-contact">Submit</button>
 </form>
 </div>
```

Here I used Ajax to send email. From here I can successfully pass all these 3 parameter. I checked in chrome via debugging. I am getting all 3 values.

THIS IS MY AJAX CALL.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#email-button').click(function() {
           name = $('#name').val();
           email = $('#email').val();
           message2 = $('#message1').val();
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "email.php",
                    data: "name=" + name + "email=" + email + "message3=" + message2,

                     success: function (html) {
                     if (html == "true") {
                       $('#form').remove();
                       $('#response').html("<p>Thank you for your message. I'll get back to you ASAP </p>");
                     }
                     else {
                       $('#form').remove();
                       $('#response').html("<p> Something Wrong </p>");

                     }
                     }
                    });
                       return false;

                    });
                    });
```

But in my PHP code I am not able to store anything in `$message` variable. It's not storing any value in this variable. I tried with echo `$message`  but it's showing me empty string.

THIS IS MY email.php FILE

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
      $name = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
    }
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
      $email = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
    }
    if(isset($_POST['message3'])) {
      $message = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['message3']));
    }

      $header = "Name:" . $name . "Email:" . $email ;
      $to = "xyz@gmail.com";
      $subject = "From My website";

      mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
      echo "true";
   ?>
```

Even in mail I am getting only Subject. Not header nor Message.I am not able to find my mistake. I am getting Name and Email via echo $header; but with same syntax I am not able to see $message. It's giving me empty string only.

Comment: So what _does_ `$_POST` contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
data:{"name":  name,  "email" : email,  "message3" : message2}
```